# $\mathbb{Z}_p \hookrightarrow R$ is it necessary $R$ commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $R$ be an integral domain with $\operatorname{Char}(R)=p$, with $p$ prime. Then:
$$\mathbb{Z}_p \hookrightarrow R$$
The proof is not difficult. My questions are:

1) Is it necessary to have an commutative ring or we can generalize it for any ring with $1_R$?

2) Is it necessary $p$ to be prime?

Please explain your answers.

Comment: It is preferable to use $\mathbb Z/p$ or $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ to notate what you're calling $\mathbb Z_p$. The latter is often used to notate the $p$-adic integers, a completely different object.

Answer (score 1):

If $R$ is any ring with identity $1_R$, then the subring generated by $1_R$ is a commutative subring with the same characteristic as $R$. $\Bbb Z$ maps onto this subring in all cases.

If the characteristic is positive, it means that this mapping of $\Bbb Z$ into $R$ has a nontrivial kernel $(n)$, and so the image has $n$ elements ($n>1$).

Clearly if $ab=n$ is a nontrivial factorization of a composite $n$, then $a$ and $b$ are zero divisors. The only way there can't be zero divisors is if $n$ is a prime number.

Comment: Can we find an easier way to proove my questions? Thank you!

Comment: @Chris Which part is not easy?